# How to post data in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have written this code to post data in the url but is not working, this is my Json file

```
[{
        "id": 9,
        "questionnairename": "sfdsdf",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "questionnairecontent": null,
        "answername": null,
        "mosha": null,
        "gjinia": null,
        "komuna": null,
        "emri": null,
        "email": null,
        "importanttopics": null,
        "selectedparties": null,
        "session": null
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "questionnairename": null,
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null,
        "questionnairecontent": null,
        "answername": null,
        "mosha": null,
        "gjinia": null,
        "komuna": null,
        "emri": null,
        "email": null,
        "importanttopics": null,
        "selectedparties": null,
        "session": null
    },
```

This is my code:

```
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View ,Button} from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
    // data: [],
    text:"",
    questionnairename:""

  };

  postData=async()=>{
    let anketaData = new anketaData();
    anketaData.append("id","0");
    anketaData.append("questionnairename","ermira");

    this.setState({text:"ermira"})
    fetch("http://192.168.0.100:8000/anketa/testd?method=get",{
      method:"POST",
      body:anketaData
    }).then((response)=>response())
    .then((responseJson)=>{
      this.setState({text:JSON.stringify(responseJson)})
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button onPress={this.postData} title="Post data"></Button>
        <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={(x, i) => i}
          renderItem={({ item }) =>
            <Text>
              {item.questionnairename} 
            </Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    marginTop: 15,
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  }
});
```

This is the error:

> "Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id:0)":
>   TypeError: undefined is not a contructor(evaluating "new anketaData()")

Comment: What is `new anketaData()`?

Comment: I have found this in the internet something.append, can you help me to modify the **async function**???

Comment: You need to post object right? But what is use of `new anketaData()` in your code?

Comment: I have tried to post a object with new **anketaData()**

Comment: Can't you work with simple object

Comment: No, the format of JSON is array of objects in the backend and i have to post data there

Comment: `new anketaData()` is creating array for you?

Comment: I think you should directly use this `let anketaData = {"id":"0","questionnairename":"ermira"}`

Comment: please check my answer - var formData = new FormData();

Answer (score 0):

let anketaData = new anketaData() **Replace with**

**var formData = new FormData();**

- Also you can post data using below method

```js
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    firstParam: 'yourValue',
    secondParam: 'yourOtherValue',
  }),
});
```

Comment: state = {
    text:"",
    questionnairename:"",
    id:""
   
  };
  postData=async()=>{
    fetch('http://192.168.0.100:8000/api/anketa/testd', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        firstParam: 'id',
        secondParam: '1700',
      }),
    });
  }

Comment: render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button onPress={this.postData} title="Post data"></Button>
        <Text>{this.state.id}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

Comment: This is my code now, i have no errors but still not showing the data, is the state ok and the rendering?

Answer (score 0):

```
method: 'POST',
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
body: JSON.stringify({
mosha: TextInputName,
komuna: TextInputEmail,
emri: TextInputPhoneNumber
})
}).then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {
Alert.alert(responseJson);
}).catch((error) => {
console.error(error);
});
```